# How to equalize Arabic/Farsi font size with Latin fonts in the terminal?

Tags: terminal, fonts

**tl;dr:** How to equalize font sizes for Arabic/Farsi with the Latin ones in the terminal?

**Context:** I'm finding a workaround for vim's [outdated support for Farsi](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/vim_use/farsi%7Csort:date/vim_use/4-Uu3jkqBDY/C_qAM-DrAQAJ).

I've gotten far enough with vim's configuration (to be updated in the previous link) except for the fact that the Latin fonts are much bigger than their Arabic counterpart (SE may scale the image and give the impression that it is bigger than it actually is):

[image: Very unreadable]

One workaround was to increase the terminal font size which renders the Arabic alphabet at least readable:

[image: Scales size.]

However the Latin fonts are too big. Ideally I would like them balanced.

I believe this to be more related to the terminal than to vim itself.

Details:

- I'm invoking the Farsi friendly vim instance with [mlterm](http://mlterm.sourceforge.net/).
- I'm using a [Lubuntu OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lubuntu).